# Flickering and sudden resolution changes on 20.04 and old Radeon HD 6570 card

Tags: drivers, gnome, display, 20.04, amd-graphics

Initially, Ubuntu started with far lower resolution than my monitor. I've tried `xrandr --newmode` command*, it temporarily helps to get back to my original 1600X900 resolution. But now screen sometimes go back to that lower resolution (and randpomly comes back to normal after some time), and `xrandr` doesn't help.

Plus, my screen keeps flickering, sometimes quite frequently. Combined with low resolution, it has become almost unbearable at this point. Things work alright with windows 10 (dual boot).

Output using `lspci -k` command:

```
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks PRO [Radeon HD 6570/7570/8550]
Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Turks PRO [Radeon HD 6570/7570/8550]
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
```

No possible driver update shown in Software & Update.

**Edits** with further details:

1. Sometimes, but not always, simply going to Display Setting by GUI or
   typing `xrandr` in command line fixes it.
2. I sometimes see "drm:radeon_vga_detect [radeon]] *ERROR* VGA-1: probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID" while shutting down or in
   `/var/log/syslog`. Also quite frequently "ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)]
   Too short EDID data: manufacturer id" in the log.
3. Using `read-edid` package, I noticed that while on low res, it can't detect EDID on any bus. However if I keep running this
   command, at some point it successfully reads & parses EDID. *Then*,
   if I go to Display Setting, or after some time automatically- the
   resolution comes back to normal.
4. Reinstalled ubuntu, removed that cron job. Didn't change the situation.
5. I've tried Wayland, `awesome` window manager, `lightdm` display manager. I'd rather not change the GNOME environment.
6. Tried Ubuntu 18.04.4, now its *always* low resolution.

**Config:** CPU: Ryzen 3700x, MB: Asus Tuf x570 Gaming plus, Kernel: `5.4.0-39-generic`

*Below script during startup using `cron`

```
xrandr --newmode $(cvt 1600 900 60 | grep Mode | sed -e 's/.*"/1600x900/')
xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1600x900
```

**Update**: **Relpacing GNOME with KDE fixed it for me- in particular a fresh installation of Kubuntu 20.04**

Comment: @Nmath, I agree...deleted the comment

Comment: Try changing your `cvt` to `cvt -r` for reduced blanking mode.